# Query Suggestions Dashboard in Algolia?

Tags: algolia

I've been looking through the Algolia documentation for Query Suggestions (https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/analytics/query-suggestions/#query-suggestions---what-is-it) and it states, "The dashboard is available in the business and enterprise plans. You can use our Query Suggestions dashboard to do everything you need in order to manage the data and configuration."

I have a Business Plan -- is there a specific "Query Suggestions" dashboard that allows me to configure how it works? I've found that the Algolia documentation is poor and vague in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ask Algolia to enable it, from the page you linked (it's very easy to miss): "This feature is available to all Business & Enterprise customers. Please reach out to the Algolia Success Team to enable this feature on your dashboard."